# Wordpress json performance, iOS app (WP REST Api vs SMIO Wordpress API Complete Solution)

Tags: json, wordpress, swift

I am writing an app for wordpress for iOS (swift). 
First of all I tried to use SMIO Wordpress API Complete Solution (wordpress json plugin codecanyon.net/item/smio-wordpress-api-complete-solution/6448487)
Works well, but have some bugs. Then I found Wp REST Api (wordpress.org/support/plugin/json-rest-api), which have more developer history. So, I decided to use to use the second plugin.

**Problem:**

SMIO Wordpress API Complete Solution load last 10 posts in 5 sec,
Wp REST Api - 20-30 sec.

Swift code: `let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: self.url!)!`

Why?

I use wp super cache (https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-super-cache/). Default settings.